# Reference question for a generalization of vertex coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am wondering whether there is a standard convention for the following generalization of the vertex coloring.

An $n$-diameter coloring is a vertex coloring such that vertices between which there exists a path of length $\leq n$ have distinct colors. So the usual coloring would be $1$-diameter coloring.

Comment: This is just an ordinary coloring of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually called a distance colouring.

See the survey by Kramer and Karmer,

[https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X0700386X#:~:text=A%20distance%2Dcolouring%20relative%20to,than%20p%20have%20distinct%20colours](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X0700386X#:%7E:text=A%20distance%2Dcolouring%20relative%20to,than%20p%20have%20distinct%20colours).